# How do you remove weeds from a weed mat?

Tags: weed-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I bake weeds out of my landscaping?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1656/how-do-i-bake-weeds-out-of-my-landscaping)
>   [How to stop grass growing through landscape pebbles?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2312/how-to-stop-grass-growing-through-landscape-pebbles)

How do you best remove weeds that have infiltrated a weed mat covered with medium sized marble chips. I have a japanese garden, the weed mat was laid down by the landscaper about 6 years ago, covered with marble chips that are about 1/2-1"thick, some bare spots, and each year more weeds creek up through the mat and are impossible to pull out. Must I rip up the entire area and start again. He did kill the entire area with a chemcial before putting the weed mat down. Deer and debris from neighboring trees get on the marble chips.

Comment: What part of the world are you in?

Answer (score 6):

This answer [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1656/how-do-i-bake-weeds-out-of-my-landscaping?rq=1) will help you.  You can bake them out with hot sun.  Other solutions are pickling vinegar poured on the plants.  Boiling water works on top growth but can lead to burns if it splashes.

The key thing is to prevent regrowth.  You could add more marble chips but if it was my garden I would rake out the marble chips and put new fabric on top of the old fabric and then rake the marble chips back.